# twisted logic: a global variable in one file refers to an extern variable but is also referred by that extern variable

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, external

fileA.cpp：

```
#include <iostream>
extern int iA;
extern int iB= iA;
int main()
{
std::cout<<iA<<','<<iB;
}
```

fileB.cpp

```
extern int iB;
extern int iA = 2*iB;
```

Compiled and linked and ran, out come in the debug and release mode is `0,0`
My question is how it works, why there is no issue in linking stage?
I'm using VC++2003.

Comment: gcc reports: `fileb.cpp:2: warning: 'iA' initialized and declared 'extern'
 extern int iA = 2*iB;
            ^`

Comment: @PiotrNycz No warning in VisualStudio.  What gcc gave does not looks like a warning at all. I bet it would gave the same warning if i have:    extern int iA = 10;

Comment: Yes, you will have the same warning, btw  - gcc also produces `0,0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialiser overrides the `extern` keyword, so there's nothing "magical" about this: you're just declaring and defining two completely unrelated variables in different translation units.

From [Standard for Programming Language C++ - Chapter 3.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf):

> **A declaration is a *definition* unless** it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), **it contains the `extern` specifier** (7.1.1) or a *linkage-specification*<sup>25</sup> (7.5) **and neither an initializer** nor a *function-body*, it declares a static data member in a class definition (9.2, 9.4), it is a class name declaration (9.1), it is an *opaque-enum-declaration* (7.2), it is a *template-parameter* (14.1), it is a *parameter-declaration* (8.3.5) in a function declarator that is not the declarator of a *function-definition*, or it is a `typedef` declaration (7.1.3), an *alias-declaration* (7.1.3), a *using-declaration* (7.3.3), a *static_assert-declaration* (Clause 7), an *attribute-declaration* (Clause 7), an *empty-declaration* (Clause 7), or a *using-directive* (7.3.4).

Your program is thus equivalent to the following:

*fileA.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
extern int iA;
int iB= iA;
int main()
{
std::cout<<iA<<','<<iB;
}
```

*fileB.cpp*

```
extern int iB;
int iA = 2*iB;
```

Both objects necessarily undergo static initialization (to bitwise all-zeroes) before anything else happens. When dynamic-initialization later takes place, depending on whether the static-storage-duration objects in fileA.cpp or fileB.cpp get initialised first (and you *can't know* what order that'll be) either `iB` is initialized to a zero `iA` (then `iA` is initialized to `2*iB` as expected), or `iA` is initialised to a zero `iB` multiplied by two, which is still zero (then `iB` is initialized to a zero `iA`).

Either way, both objects are going to end up, via well-defined semantics, having a value of zero.

Comment: I believe this is not undefined behaviour but unspecified behaviour. As stated in `3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.init]` - there are two phases of initialization - static and dynamic. static initialization in this case causes that variables are zeroed. Then dynamic initialization does not change this state. The order of dynamic initialization from different source units is unspecified - but both of possible orders give the same result.

Comment: Snuck a fix over the border

Comment: Zero initialization (which is the alternative to constant initialization in static initialization) sets a variable to value zero, which is probably all bits zero, but need not be.